# Loading Images from URL Is Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am loading images from Wikipedia into a Grid view.  For the most part this is working correctly.  Because there could possible be up to 200 or more images being loaded I am try to run it in a new thread.  I see a definite delay when scrolling from my Album tab to the Artist tab that is loading the images.  I am also see some lag as images are still getting load while scrolling up and down the list.  Also when I scroll back to the top of the list place holders that previously occupied by the default image because I am unable to get an image from Wikipedia are now occupied by images from another artist.

When I scroll back to the song list and then back to the artist list the view is reset but it still has a lot of delay when going into the artist tab.

This image is what the screen looks like when first entering the Artist tab.

[image]

This image is what the screen looks like after scrolling to the bottom of the list and back to the top.

[image]

As you can see the <unknow. and AJR have had their default image replaced.

Here is my code that I am calling to load the images from Wikipedia.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ARV holder, int position) {

    Artist artist = artistList.get(position);
    if(artist!=null) {
        holder.artistName.setText(artist.artistName);
        String bandName = artist.artistName;
        bandName = bandName.replace(' ','_');
        try {
            String imageUrl = cutImg(getUrlSource("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles="+bandName+"&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=250"));
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, holder.artistImage,
                    new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.album)
                            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getCoverArtPath(context,artist.id),holder.artistImage,
                new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.album)
                        .resetViewBeforeLoading(false).build());*/
        }
}

private StringBuilder getUrlSource(String site) throws IOException {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    URL localUrl = null;
    localUrl = new URL(site);
    URLConnection conn = localUrl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    String html;
    StringBuilder ma = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ma.append(line);
        Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "StringBuilder " + ma);
    }
    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "Final StringBuilder " + ma);
    return ma;
}

public static String cutImg(StringBuilder split){
    int start=split.indexOf("\"source\":")+new String("\"source\":\"").length();
    split.delete(0, start);
    split.delete(split.indexOf("\""), split.length());
    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "StringBuilder " + split);
    return split.toString();
}
```

Here is the code that is call the Artist Fragment.

```
public class ArtistFragment extends Fragment {

    int spanCount = 3; // 2 columns
    int spacing = 20; // 20px
    boolean includeEdge = true;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArtistAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.artistFragment);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // put whatever code you want to run inside the thread here.
                new LoadData().execute("");
            }
        };

        t.start();
        return view;
    }

    public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            if(getActivity()!=null) {
                adapter=new ArtistAdapter(getActivity(),new ArtistLoader().artistList(getActivity()));
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if(getActivity()!=null) {
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this using Picasso using the following code:

```
 bandName = artist.artistName;
    bandName = bandName.replace(' ','_');
    try {
           String imageUrl = cutImg(getUrlSource("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles="+bandName+"&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=250"));
                    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.album)
                            .error(R.drawable.artistdefault).into(holder.artistImage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The results are pretty much the same as when I used Android-Universal-Image-Loader. I have been try for several days to fix this, I have tried several different examples that I found on Stack overflow but none of them seem to resolve the issues I am seeing.  I am hoping that someone will be able to identify what I am doing incorrectly.
Thanks in advance.

ArtistFragmentconverted to Kotlin

```
class ArtistFragment : Fragment() {
var spanCount = 3 // 2 columns
var spacing = 20 // 20px
var includeEdge = true

var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
var wikiService: WikiService? = null
var adapter: ArtistAdapter? = null

private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

private var viewModelJob = Job()
private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

private var progress_view: ProgressBar? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.artistFragment)
    recyclerView?.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(activity, 3))
    progress_view = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_view)
    initWikiService()
    initList()
    //LoadData().execute("")
    return view
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    viewModelJob.cancel()
}

private fun initList() {
    recyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge))
    adapter = ArtistAdapter(this)
    adapter?.items = ArrayList()
    adapter?.listener = this
    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter

    viewModelScope.launch {
        progress_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val wikiPages = getWikiPages()
        adapter?.items = wikiPages
        progress_view?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

private suspend fun getWikiPages(): ArrayList<Artist> {
    val newItems = ArrayList<Artist>()

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ArtistData.artists.map { artist ->

            async { wikiService?.getWikiData(artist) }
        }.awaitAll().forEach { response ->
            val pages = response?.body()?.query?.pages
            pages?.let {
                for (page in pages) {
                    val value = page.value
                    val id = value.pageid?.toLong() ?: value.title.hashCode().toLong()
                    val title = value.title ?: "Unknown"
                    val url = value.thumbnail?.source
                    newItems.add(Artist(id, title, albumCount = 0, songCount = 0, artistUrl = url!!))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newItems
}

private fun initWikiService() {
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    wikiService = retrofit?.create(WikiService::class.java)
}
```

I believe I have resolved most of the issues I was previously seeing I am now down to the following problems:

`Artist.item.map { artist ->` - Not sure how this should be called, Unresolved reference: item

`}.awaitAll().forEach { response ->` = forEach is telling me Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public inline fun  Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) → Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) → Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

`newItems.add(Artist(id, title, url))` - I know that the variables for the Artist Model need to go here, but when I put them there they are unresolved.

I have reworked the ArtistAdapter not sure if it is correct though.

```
class ArtistAdapter(private val context: ArtistFragment, private val artistList: List<Artist>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistAdapter.ARV>() {

private var dimension: Int = 64

init {
    val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    dimension = (density * 64).toInt()
    hasStableIds()
}

var items: MutableList<Artist> = ArrayList()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

var listener: Listener? = null

interface Listener {
    fun onItemClicked(item: Artist)
    abstract fun ArtistAdapter(context: ArtistFragment): ArtistAdapter
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ARV {
    return ARV(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.artist_gride_item, parent,
            false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ARV, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(getItem(position))
}

private fun getItem(position: Int): Artist = items[position]

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = items[position].id

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return artistList?.size ?: 0
}

inner class ARV(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

    private val artistNameView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName)
    private val artistAlbumArtView: SquareCellView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistAlbumArt)

    fun onBind(item: Artist) {
        artistNameView.text=item.artistName

        if(item.artistURL!=null) {
            Picasso.get()
                        .load(item.artistURL)
                        .resize(dimension, dimension)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(R.drawable.artistdefualt)
                        .into(artistAlbumArtView)
        } else {
            artistAlbumArtView.setImageResource(R.drawable.artistdefualt)
        }
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        val artistId = artistList!![bindingAdapterPosition].id
        val fragmentManager = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment: Fragment
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.layout_fad_in, R.anim.layout_fad_out,
                R.anim.layout_fad_in, R.anim.layout_fad_out)
        fragment = ArtistDetailsFragment.newInstance(artistId)
        transaction.hide(context.supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.main_container)!!)
        transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
}
```

}

Logcat Snippet

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or it

    s super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
            at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
            at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
            at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
            at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
            at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
            at com.rvogl.androidaudioplayer.fragments.ArtistFragment.initWikiService(ArtistFragment.kt:103)
            at com.rvogl.androidaudioplayer.fragments.ArtistFragment.onCreateView(ArtistFragment.kt:43)
```

Comment: Why did you put the asynctask call in the run of a thread? Remove the thread. It makes no sense.

Comment: If artist== null you should set your default image.

Comment: If I remove the thread it is even more laggy. I did this because logcat was telling that the UI thread was doing to much work.  As for the artist==null, there is always an artist. UIL is setting the default image with the  .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.album), I don't understand you comments.

Comment: Did you hear about Glide or Picasso libraries?

Comment: @Nirel yes I have heard about Picasso and Glide. I am using Picasso and Universal Image Loader to load the images.  This is not what I am asking about.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as a known bug with Picasso.
Try to load default image manually so it won't be replaced with cached one.

Update 14.10.20:
I think the main problem is that you load network content in adapter in rather ineffective way. I suggest to form a list of all urls at first, leaving only image load in adapter.

Also reccomend you to use rerofit2 for network calls and something for async work instead of AsyncTask: rxJava, courutines, flow etc.

I created a sample project to load data async using retrofit2+coroutines.

**In activity:**

```
private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

private fun initWikiService() {
    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    wikiService = retrofit?.create(WikiService::class.java)
}

private fun initList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val wikiPages = getWikiPages()
        adapter?.items = wikiPages
    }
}
private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

private suspend fun getWikiPages(): ArrayList<Item> {
    val newItems = ArrayList<Item>()

    withContext(IO) {
        ArtistData.artists.map { artist ->
            async { wikiService?.getWikiData(artist) }
        }.awaitAll().forEach { response ->
            val pages = response?.body()?.query?.pages
            pages?.let {
                for (page in pages) {
                    val value = page.value
                    val id = value.pageid?.toLong() ?: value.title.hashCode().toLong()
                    val title = value.title ?: "Unknown"
                    val url = value.thumbnail?.source
                    newItems.add(Item(id, title, url))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newItems
}
```

**In viewHolder:**

```
    fun onBind(item: Item) {
        if (item.url != null) {
            Picasso.get()
                .load(item.url)
                .resize(dimension, dimension)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_broken_image_24)
                .into(pictureView)
        } else {
            pictureView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_24)
        }
    }
```

**In adapter:** add hasStableIds() to constructor and override getItemId method:

```
init {
    hasStableIds()
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = items[position].id
```

**Retrofit Service:**

```
interface WikiService {
    @GET("/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=250")
    suspend fun getWikiData(@Query("titles") band: String): Response<WikipediaResponse?>
}
```

Comment: No this did not fix the issue. The default image still gets replaced and it is still laggy on entering the and scrolling the Artist tab.

Comment: VasiliyT I am not all that familiar with Kotlin.  Am I able to mix my current code with the code you have provided?

Comment: Yes, Java and Kotlin mix fine together. Also you can relatively easy convert to java by replacing property access with getters, ? with null checks and so on.

Comment: would it be possible for you to provide the above code in Java.  I am having a hard time rewriting it and incorporating into my own.

Comment: Won't be easy to move corroutines to java. I better leave a link to the repository with a sample code https://github.com/VasylT/NetworkingTestApp

Comment: I am trying to bring in your code.  Should I be converting my ArtistFragment class to Kotlin and inserting the call you made in the MainActivity of your sample?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help so far. I have run into a few error that I am unsure of how to resolve.  I have posted them above.  Could you please advise on how to resolve them.

Comment: Try to think before copypasting. 
You have no progress_view view in your layout - add it or delete all lines with it mentioned. Also you don't have wikiPages. Other errors require full ArtistAdapter code posted. And anyway it's already the topic for the seperate question

Comment: Yes I realized there was no progress_view and I did update code above with it.  Not sure I understand what you mean about not having wikiPages.  I have put the ArtistAdapter code that I converted from Java to Kotlin above.

Comment: I believe I have this pretty much figured out.  I just have one question in your function getWikiPages your are reading the data in from ArtistData which is predefined list.  How can I map ArtistData.artists.map { artist -> async { wikiService?.getWikiData(artist) } to read from the songs that are actual on the device.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts with this.  I am having to many issues getting your code incorporated in to mine.  I will revisit this should I want to implement this in the future.